# Does Python have the equivalent of io.TextIOWrapper() for binary streams, e.g. for a compression algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out which part of the `io` or `codecs` modules would be the best way to implement a binary stream filter, e.g. `Decompressor(output).write(b'compressed')` writes decompressed data to the `output` stream. Is there something like an `io.BytesIOWrapper` as the bytes equivalent to `io.TextIOWrapper`? I would `write()` data into the Decompressor, it would decompress the data, and `write()` the decompressed data to output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode a text stream into a byte stream in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585110/how-to-encode-a-text-stream-into-a-byte-stream-in-python-3)

Comment: That question demonstrates a pull-based "read" instead of a push-based "write" API.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best examples I've found for the `io` module is the hidden `_compression` module. The various compression algorithms supported by Python inherit from these classes. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_compression.py